# How can I best debug a Python crash due to SIGSEVG in QNX?

Tags: python-3.x, shared-libraries, ctypes, qnx

I have compiled shared C++ libraries in QNX containing a target function. I have executed the function from C++ without errors. I created a one line C wrapper of the function and called that from C++ with no errors. However when I attempt to call the function by loading the shared library in Python 3.8.8 for QNX using ctypes built-in, it executes some of the code, then crashes at the same point every time with the memory fault. I am using the Momentics IDE and looking for some advice on how to narrow down what the issue might be.

I am new to QNX. have tried using some of the momentics IDE resources, such as memory analyzer but they don't seem to function out of box on my target. I have stepped through the C++ code in the debugger with no issues. Since the process that is crashing is Python, it makes things a bit challenging to debug from the IDE.

Comment: It makes things a bit challenging when you have shown no code. Show the Python code and at least the C prototype you are trying to call.